# How to delete information from array

Tags: arrays, c

Im trying to delete information from this created array Customer. The array contains the information, firstname, lastname, checkingbalance,savingsbalance, moneymarketbalance,accountnumber and balance. The information is saved and called upon later. I have to be able to delete them and I want to do it using the account number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Customer
{
    char FirstName[100];
    char LastName[100];
    int CheckingBalance;
    int SavingsBalance;
    int MoneyMarketBalance;
    int AccountNumber;
    float Balance;
};

struct Customer customer[20]; 

int NumOfAccounts;
 
void NewAccount()
{
    char FirstName[100];
    char LastName[100];
    int CheckingBalance;
    int SavingsBalance;
    int MoneyMarketBalance;
    int AccountNumber;
    float Balance = 0;

    printf("You have chosen that you want to become a new member of Global Bank! Please enter your first name:\n");
    scanf("%s", FirstName);
    printf("Thank you! Now please enter your last name:\n");
    scanf("%s", LastName);
    printf("Thank you %s %s for entering your name!", FirstName, LastName);
    printf("\nEnter how much would you like to deposit into your checking account: \n");
    scanf("%d", &CheckingBalance); 
    printf("Thank you %s for your initial deposit of %d!", FirstName, CheckingBalance);
    printf("\nEnter how much would you like to deposit into your savings account: \n");
    scanf("%d", &SavingsBalance); 
    printf("Thank you %s for your initial deposit of %d!", FirstName, SavingsBalance);
    printf("\nEnter how much would you like to deposit into your Money Market account: \n");
    scanf("%d", &MoneyMarketBalance); 
    printf("Thank you %s for your initial deposit of %d!", FirstName, MoneyMarketBalance);
    printf("\nNow choose your custom account number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &AccountNumber);
    printf("\nWelcome %s %s to Global Bank. Your account number is %d your initial balance in your checking is %d and your initial balance in your savings is %d.", FirstName, LastName, AccountNumber, CheckingBalance, SavingsBalance);
    printf("\n\nIf you would like to check the bank balance of your account press '2'. \nIf you would like to close your account, press '3'. \nIf you would like to make a deposit, press '4'. \nIf you would like to make a withdrawal, press '5'. \nIf you would like to check all members last names, press '6'. \nIf you would like to exit press '7'.\n"); 

    strcpy(customer[AccountNumber-1].FirstName,FirstName);
    strcpy(customer[AccountNumber-1].LastName,LastName);
    (customer[AccountNumber-1].AccountNumber=AccountNumber);
    (customer[AccountNumber-1].CheckingBalance=CheckingBalance);
    (customer[AccountNumber-1].SavingsBalance=SavingsBalance);
    (customer[AccountNumber-1].MoneyMarketBalance=MoneyMarketBalance);

    NumOfAccounts++;
}

void CloseAccount()
{
char FirstName[100];
char LastName[100];
int CheckingBalance;
int SavingsBalance;
int MoneyMarketBalance;
int AccountNumber;
int i;
printf("\nYou have chosen that you want to close your account. Enter your account number: \n");
scanf("%d", &customer->AccountNumber);
while (1)
{
memset(&customer[AccountNumber-1], 0, sizeof customer[AccountNumber-1]);
break;
}
printf("\nYou have closed your account. We are sad to see you go.\n");
}
}

int main()
{

    int choice;
    printf("Welcome to the Global Bank app! \nIf you would like to become a new member, press '1'. \nIf you would like to check the bank balance of your account press '2'. \nIf you would like to close your account, press '3'. \nIf you would like to make a deposit, press '4'. \nIf you would like to make a withdrawal, press '5'. \nIf you would like to check all members last names, press '6'. \nIf you would like to exit press '7'.\n"); 
    while(1){
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            NewAccount();
            break;

            case 2:
            case 3:
                CloseAccount();
            case 4:
            break;
            case 5:

            break;
            case 6:

            case 7:
            printf("Have a good day and thank you for banking with Global Bank!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I cant think of a way to do it (probably because its super late). Also what are these:

```
strcpy(customer[AccountNumber-1].LastName,LastName);
(customer[AccountNumber-1].AccountNumber=AccountNumber);
```

called? I don't know how to search for them on the internet and I think its hindering me a little.

PS:

If there is anything wrong with the formatting of the question or something please dont close this post ive been up working on the other parts of the program and I will fix the formatting when I wake up. Thank you

Comment: You can't really *delete* elements of an array, as arrays have a fixed size. You can however copy over elements with other data.

Comment: so would you recommend using like strcpy and replacing everything with a white space?

Comment: On another note, in your `NewAccount` function, why redefine all the variables already in your structure? You can declare an object of your `Customer` structure, read into its members, and then just assign it to the array element. The last part, assigning to the array element, should also give a hint about how to solve your problem.

Comment: Instead of copying each field of your struct you can just copy a whole element of your array: `customer[AccountNumber-1] = customer[AccountNumber]`. But you must be aware that `AccountNumber` in your struct does not necessarily match the index of the array, especially after removing one of the entries.

Comment: TZZR-Gaming,  `scanf("%s", ...);` without a _width_ is bad coding practice.  Use a width like `scanf("%99s", FirstName);`.  BTW, first names and last names may include spaces, thus `"%s"` in insufficient.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you know what to call `customer[AccountNumber-1] = customer[AccountNumber].`? Like how would I search something like it on the internet

Comment: Instead of moving entries you can simply have a flag in each entry saying if it's active or not

Comment: @pm100 Would you recommend using like an if nested while loop that would set each value to null?

Comment: Perhaps `c assignment between structures` as a search term?

Comment: no, just have a flag that says if an ebtry is valid or not, skip non valid entries when searchinf, printing etc

Answer (score 1):

> How to delete information from array (?)

Once an array is defined, its size cannot change.  Thus an array element cannot get deleted.

OP could simply use `NumOfAccounts--` to prevent access to the last account.

If an earlier indexed account is to be deleted, perhaps copy the last one to it and then `NumOfAccounts--`.

**Deeper**

Code can overwrite an array:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof array);
```

... or an array element:

```
memset(&array[i], 0, sizeof array[i]);
```

If that memory is not potential read later, the call could be optimized out.  Yet I suspect for OP's proposes, this is not a concern.

Comment: I used your suggestion with the memset. It deletes the most recent element rather than the specified one. I have updated the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: @TZZR-Gaming "It deletes the most recent element rather than the specified one." --> `memset(&array[i], 0, sizeof array[i]);` will zero out the element indexed by `i`.  Use the right `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just manually set each value to null. I'm sure there are better ways but this works well enough.

```
void CloseAccount()
{
char FirstName[100];
char LastName[100];
int CheckingBalance;
int SavingsBalance;
int MoneyMarketBalance;
int AccountNumber;
int i;
printf("\nYou have chosen that you want to close your account. Enter your account number: \n");
scanf("%d", &customer->AccountNumber);
while (AccountNumber=customer[AccountNumber-1].AccountNumber)
{
customer[AccountNumber-1].CheckingBalance = NULL;
customer[AccountNumber-1].SavingsBalance = NULL;
customer[AccountNumber-1].MoneyMarketBalance = NULL;
break;
}
printf("\nYou have closed your account. We are sad to see you go.\n");
}
```

Comment: Although very common, `NULL`, a _null pointer constant_, when converted to an `int` is not certainly 0.  Save `NULL` for _pointers_.  Here just use `0`. `customer[AccountNumber-1].CheckingBalance = 0;`

Comment: Objects `char FirstName[100]; char LastName[100]; int CheckingBalance; int SavingsBalance; int MoneyMarketBalance; int AccountNumber; int i;` have no use here.  Consider deleting them.